# Why do we need to add additional dependency for log42j in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, log4j2

Why do we need to add an additional dependency for log42j since all the transitive dependencies are already present in spring-boot-starter-web?
From whatever tutorials I could read up on the internet everybody mentioned to add the dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

They also mentioned excluding `spring-boot-starter-logging` from `spring-boot-starter-web`.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But why do we need to do this? I see all the dependencies in `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` are already there in `spring-boot-starter-logging`.

Comment: I dont think this is even required if you are using latest spring boot version. I tried to find the PR/issue related to this but couldnt find. Almost all blogs which talk about excluding are using older spring boot versions.

Comment: The latest doc I could find for 2.3.x indicates that the exclusions are still required if you are using the spring-boot-starter dependencies.

Comment: The dependencies are in `spring-boot-dependencies` NOT in `spring-boot-starter-logging` they only contain the [default Logback](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.3.1.RELEASE/jar) is in there (with an API for log4j to route it through SLF4J). The default logging framework is still Logback and not Log4j2. So if you want to switch you need to exclude the default logger and include log4j2.

Comment: @M.Deinum I generated a UML of dependency tree and I can clearly see that all the dependencies in spring-boot-starter-logging are covered by spring-boot-starter-logging. I understand that Logback is the default logging framework but if I use the following import statements, I think I am using log42j only

`import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`

Comment: Looking at the pom it isn't (that is what I linked) so something else must be pulling in those dependencies, they are in the dependency-management section but that doesn't make them a dependency!. And if you are using the imports you are using actually 2 logging frameworks if logback is still on the classpath. The parts through slf4j probably go to logback and the rest to log4j2. In otherwords you created a mess.

Comment: If you try to generate a UML, you'll see that the dependencies are common except for additional Logback dependencies in spring-boot-starter-logging. "The parts through slf4j probably go to logback and the rest to log4j2." Please elaborate on this. What is rest in this?

Answer (score 0):

The default dependency for logging is not log4j but logback. If you remove the dependency, ideally speaking you should not be able to use the log4j imports in your project. Can you check this once?
The log4j dependency is only declared in the dependency-management, but you would need to include the dependency to be able to use this declared dependency.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring by default logging is backed by Logback which is powered by Apache. So if you want to provide logging in the system you can do so using logback. Now if you are asking the question for exclusion for logback it is just for letting spring know that you are using the different logging framework.

[Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging)

Answer (score 0):

When `spring-boot-starter-logging` is included:

```xml
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.4.2:compile
+- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
+- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
|  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
\- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
```

, then [`log4j-core`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) does not exist.

On the other hand, when `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` is included:

```xml
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.4.2:compile
+- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.13.3:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
|  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
+- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
+- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.13.3:compile
\- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
```

, then it exists.